# Can't Authenticate on Ubuntu Docker Droplet for docker pull registry (Digital Ocean)

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-registry

Background:

- i am using digital ocean ubuntu docker droplet
- i have pushed my image to digital ocean container registry

Issue is I run docker pull $registry (obviously url) and it says `unauthorized: authentication required`. It looks in `/manifests/latest` which isnt something I found much on.

I have also gone through digital oceans registry login tutorial (and double checked) on the droplet using `doctl registry login` and authenticated it with the token from digital ocean. This works as I have been able to create and delete droplets from the droplet.

Where do I look now? I am out of ideas apart from continuing to poke around!
Help greatly appreciated as always.

edit:
running `doctl account get` returns my digital ocean account as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So after almost 2 hours of poking and then posing this question to the community I thought I would give it 5 more minutes.

The solution was to run `sudo snap connect doctl:dot-docker`. My understanding is this is a personal-files connection.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when I created droplet directly from Ubuntu and install docker by myself. But if I create droplet from the marketplace -> Docker  on Ubuntu  by pressing the button:
[image: Docker on ubuntu installation button on marketplace]

Then I don't have this issue. I think it's just the doctl and docker didn't connected or they aren't in the same path.